# Android: Calling java method with byte[] parameter from c++

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

I am an Android developer and new to JNI thing - what I'm trying to do is pass a byte array from c++ method to java method. Here is what my c++ method looks like:

```
void func(char* bytes) 
{
    jclass callbackClass = fJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(fJObject);
    jmethodID javaFunc = fJNIEnv->GetMethodID(callbackClass, "javaFunc", "([B)V");

    jbyteArray array = fJNIEnv->NewByteArray(sizeof(bytes));
    fJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, sizeof(bytes), (jbyte *) bytes);

    fJNIEnv->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(fJObject, callbackClass, javaFunc, array);
}
```

and here is the javaFunc method:

```
public void javaFunc(byte[] bytes) {
    ...
}
```

when I'm debugging the func method, `bytes` is pointing to an array of chars, but when I get to the `javaFunc` method, `bytes` is something like {16, 0, 0, 0} - it's nothing like what it has to be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof(bytes)` is wrong. That gives you the byte size of the `char*` pointer itself (4 in 32bit, 8 in 64bit), NOT the byte size of the data that is being pointed to.  You need to change `func()` to pass the number of `chars` in the array, ie `void func(char* bytes, int numBytes)`, or pass in a more appropriate container, like `std::vector<char>`, ie `func(const std::vector<char> &bytes)`. Then, you can use the real byte count when allocating and filling the JNI array

Comment: Also, you need to free the JNI array after `CallNonvirtualVoidMethod()` exits, ie `fJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(array);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sizeof(bytes)` is wrong. That gives you the byte size of the `char*` pointer itself (4 in 32bit, 8 in 64bit), NOT the byte size of the data that is being pointed to.

You need to change `func()` to pass in the number of `char`s in the array.  Then, you can use that number when allocating and filling the JNI array.

Also, you need to free the JNI array after `CallNonvirtualVoidMethod()` exits.

Try this:

```
void func(char* bytes, int numBytes)
{
    jclass callbackClass = fJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(fJObject);
    jmethodID javaFunc = fJNIEnv->GetMethodID(callbackClass, "javaFunc", "([B)V");

    jbyteArray array = fJNIEnv->NewByteArray(numBytes);
    fJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, numBytes, (jbyte *) bytes);

    fJNIEnv->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(fJObject, callbackClass, javaFunc, array);
    fJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(array);
}
```

Alternatively, pass in a more appropriate C++ container, like `std::vector<char>`:

```
void func(const std::vector<char> &bytes)
{
    jclass callbackClass = fJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(fJObject);
    jmethodID javaFunc = fJNIEnv->GetMethodID(callbackClass, "javaFunc", "([B)V");

    jbyteArray array = fJNIEnv->NewByteArray(bytes.size());
    fJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, bytes.size(), (jbyte *) bytes.data());

    fJNIEnv->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(fJObject, callbackClass, javaFunc, array);
    fJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'r `SetByteArrayRegion` call is wrong.

```
fJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, sizeof(bytes), (jbyte *) bytes);
```

it should be

```
fJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(fJNIEnv, array, 0, number of bytes, (jbyte *) bytes);
```

Syntax is:

```
SetByteArrayRegion(env, byteArray, from, size, a + from);
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass the `number of bytes` to `fJNIEnv->NewByteArray()` as well, as using `sizeof(bytes)` is wrong there, too